# Button style in Django

Tags: css, django, django-templates

The button should be a small vertical rectangle and the top width should stick out a little. It should also be white before pressing and crimson after pressing.

And when the pointer goes over this button, the text "Add" and when deleting, "Remove" should be displayed.

However, it's just a rectangle, and even its name doesn't change from addition to deletion (the color and style don't change either).

product_detail.html:

```
<form method= "get" action = "{% url 'add' product.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button clasa="bottonwatch" type = "submit" value = "{{ product.id }}"  name = "productid">
        <div class="addwatch">
            {% if product.watch_list %}
                addWatchlist
        </div>
        <div class="removewatch">
            {% else%}
                remove
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </button>
    
</form>
```

Style:

```
.bottonwatch {
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 2.5rem;
    min-width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 2.5rem;
}

.addwatch {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}

.remove{
    color: white;
    background-color: rgb(100, 36, 36);
}
```

views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url="login")
def add(request, productid):
    product_id = request.GET.get('productid', False)
    watch = Watchlist.objects.filter(user = request.user.username)


    for items in watch:
        if (items.watch_list.all) == int(productid):  
            return watchlist(request, request.user.username)
        else:
            return remove(request, productid)
    

   new_watch = Watchlist(product_id, user=request.user.username)
   new_watch.save()
   messages.success(request, "The product has been added to your WatchList.")
   return product_detail(request, productid)


@login_required(login_url="login")
def remove(request, pid):
    list_ = get_object_or_404(Watchlist, pk = pid)
    messages.success(request, "The product was removed from your WatchList.")
    list_.delete()
    return redirect("index")
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to structure your button text differently based on the conditions.

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'add' product.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button class="buttonwatch{% if product.watch_list %} in-watchlist{% endif %}" type="submit" value="{{ product.id }}" name="productid">
        <span class="button-text">
            {% if product.watch_list %}
                Remove
            {% else %}
                Add
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </button>
</form>

/* Button Style */
.buttonwatch {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

/* Default Style */
.buttonwatch .button-text {
    color: black;
}

/* Styles for 'Add' State */
.buttonwatch:not(.in-watchlist) {
    background-color: white;
}

/* Styles for 'Remove' State */
.buttonwatch.in-watchlist {
    background-color: crimson;
    color: white;
}

/* Hover Style */
.buttonwatch:hover:not(.in-watchlist) {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

/* Pressed Style */
.buttonwatch:active {
    background-color: crimson;
    color: white;
}
```

correct the CSS class names in both your HTML and CSS. The structure should be a span element within the button to allow the dynamic change of text based on conditions. Additionally, apply styles to the span with class addwatch to change background and text colors.

Comment: Thanks, but I want a button that will be colored after adding and show that the product is in the list. For example, when it shows the add button and adds the product to the list, it will be green and when it shows the remove button. It's red in color.And most importantly, the name of the button is remove and doesn't  change.

Answer (score 0):

I saw some problems in the problem you raised that might help:

- you have remove class in style file, but you use removewatch in the template.
- put div in condition

  ```
  {% if product.watch_list %}
   <div class="addwatch">
           addWatchlist
   </div>
   <div class="remove">
       {% else%}
           remove
   </div>
   {% endif %}
  ```

Comment: thanks but It has no effect and it continues to be executed in the same way. In other words, the color and shape don't change, and the button only displays the add, but completes the action.